# Jmeter suite to upload 1000 multiple format files through put request

Tags: performance, jmeter

I am facing one problem during uploading multiple files on server. I implemented some logic and fetched files one by one from a folder . But in HTTP request my URL is something like {Container name} followed by {Filename}.
My problem is in filename parameter value what should i passed so that every files will be uploaded on server .
My code is as below:-

```
File folder = new File("c:\\Test1\\Test");

File[] files = folder.listFiles(new FileFilter() {
    public boolean accept(File file) {
        return file.isFile();
    }
});

for (int i=0; i < files.length; i++) {
    vars.put("file_" + i, files[i].getAbsolutePath());
}
```

In file path i am passing this ${filesToUpload}  ,parameter name and mimetype

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your way is correct (unless you want to build the full raw body), you should rather invoke [HTTPSamplerBase.setHTTPFiles()](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/sampler/HTTPSamplerBase.html#setHTTPFiles-org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.util.HTTPFileArg:A-) function using the following example steps:

1. Add [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) as a child of the HTTP Request sampler to which you want to add files
2. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils
   import org.apache.commons.io.filefilter.TrueFileFilter
   import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.util.HTTPFileArg

   import java.nio.file.Files

   def files = FileUtils.listFiles(new File("c:/Test1/Test"), TrueFileFilter.INSTANCE, TrueFileFilter.INSTANCE)

   def arguments = []

   files.eachWithIndex { file, index ->
       arguments.add(new HTTPFileArg(file.getAbsolutePath(), "your_parameter_name", Files.probeContentType(file.toPath())))
   }

   sampler.setHTTPFiles(arguments as HTTPFileArg[])
   ```
3. That's it, the code will dynamically read the files from folder and add the files from it to the request, just make sure to amend `your_parameter_name` to the real respective value

More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: What value i will pass in file path ?

Comment: Nothing, the pre-processor will generate everything you need

Comment: 2021-02-10 10:24:23,706 ERROR o.a.j.m.JSR223PreProcessor: Problem in JSR223 script, JSR223 PreProcessor
javax.script.ScriptException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameters must not be null
 at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:320) ~[groovy-jsr223-3.0.7.jar:3.0.7]
 at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyCompiledScript.eval(GroovyCompiledScript.java:71) ~[groovy-jsr223-3.0.7.jar:3.0.7]
 at javax.script.CompiledScript.eval(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_281]

Comment: My Url is as like container name followed by the file name {which we need to upload on server) . How we will add this file name after the container name ?

Comment: If you need to upload one file at a time and need to apend the file name to the URL - the easiest option is going for [Directory Listing Config plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/introducing-directory-listing-config-plugin-jmeter). If you need to upload multiple files at a time - it doesn't make sense to add the filename to the URL as it will be only one request assuming multiple files.

Comment: Could you please guide me in my case ? I need to upload 3000 files one by one .The files are images which i kept in one folder .

Comment: Hi @Dmitri i have configured the Directory Listing and fetched all the files .Now could you please guide me further how i will  pass my URL ? Thanks in advance

Comment: I need to check the performance of my API .Other wise i need to make 3000 http request for 3000 files .